# Dynamic invocation of Delphi constructor with RTTI requires passing a boolean 'Alloc' parameter. Why?

Tags: delphi

I'm dynamically invoking constructors in Delphi using RTTI and encountered an unexpected behavior. Normally, with RTTI, I can use a `TMethod` record to hold the method's address in its `Code` field and the Self pointer in its `Data` field. However, when it comes to constructors, there seems to be a deviation.

In my endeavors to invoke a constructor, I discovered that I need to define the method type to include a specific boolean parameter Alloc as its first argument. This Alloc parameter determines whether to allocate a new instance or utilize an existing one.

Here's a distilled example:

```
type
  TMyObject = class(TObject)
    constructor Create(AOwner: TObject); virtual;
  end;

type
  _TParamSelfConstructor = function(Alloc: Boolean; Owner: TObject): TObject of object;

procedure InvokeConstructor;
var
  LContext: TRttiContext;
  LType: TRttiType;
  LMethod: TRttiMethod;
  LConstructorFunc: _TParamSelfConstructor;
  LInstance: TObject;
begin
  LContext := TRttiContext.Create;
  LType := LContext.GetType(TMyObject);
  for LMethod in LType.GetMethods do
  begin
    if LMethod.HasExtendedInfo and LMethod.IsConstructor then
    begin
      TMethod(LConstructorFunc).Code := LMethod.CodeAddress;
      TMethod(LConstructorFunc).Data := MetaclassType;
      LInstance := LConstructorFunc(True, SomeOwnerObject);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I have a few questions:

1. Why is this explicit Alloc parameter necessary for dynamic invocation of constructors, while it's typically abstracted away in direct Delphi code?
2. How does Delphi internally handle this Alloc parameter when directly invoking a constructor?
3. Are there any potential issues or caveats to be aware of when dynamically invoking constructors with this approach?

Comment: Why are you invoking the constructor manually in this manner instead of using [`TRttiMethod.Invoke()`](https://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Rtti.TRttiMethod.Invoke)?

Comment: @RemyLebeau because TRttiMethod.Invoke() is around 100 times more slower :(

Comment: then you should take that up with Embarcadero. If you are going to use RTTI, you should let the RTTI system handle these kinds of complexities for you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau but the solution a gave in sample work like a charm, same speed as if you call directlly the constructor, i just want to know some documentation about why it's work

Comment: that is covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6321723/65863) of the linked duplicate question